# Which sentence is correct?'

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

Which is correct? 'They are showing the tv program at the moment. ' or 'They are being shown the tv program at the moment.'

Comment: Both are correct, but the first 'they' is the TV company, the second 'they' refers to the viewers!

Answer (score 0):

'They are being shown the TV program at the moment' is probably what you mean. 'Showing' in this context has a very specific meaning:

> The film is showing at 9 pm

This means that at 9 pm you can watch the film at the cinema. Note that 'showing' in this context is not a gerund, and has a separate definition in the dictionary.